# C# fill out array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

I've just starting programming, and i am trying to use a for loop to fill out my array with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
I get a bunch of zeroes, anybody knows how to get the program to write 1 to 10?

```
int[] array = new int[10];

for (int i = 10; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Add this in the loop (before the `Console.WriteLine`): `array[i] = i + 1;`

Comment: You forgot to set the array values

Comment: Note that if you start at i=10, you will only see an IndexOutOfRangeException because the array has entries for indexes 0..9.

Comment: Was it just an honest mistake that you initialized `i` with the value `10`, instead of `0`?

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] array = new int[10];

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = i + 1;
    Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Note that if you start at i=10, you will only see an IndexOutOfRangeException because the array has entries for indexes 0..9